# Building docker image from the maven jar?

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile for creating the Docker image form the maven JAR. I

**DockerFile**

```
FROM  openjdk:8-jre-slim

MAINTAINER rajesh <rajesh.ganessan@letsventure.com>

ADD  target/container-test.jar /usr/share/tag/container-test.jar
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/TestRunner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <propertyName>${browser}</propertyName>
                    <propertyName>${email}</propertyName>
                    <propertyName>${password}</propertyName>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

I have already mentioned which xml file should be executed .. What should i mention in the entrypoint of the dockerfile to create a dockerimage or what should i do to execute with parameters